# The duality of dialog state. How to force the bot to check updates only in the child ConversationHandler?

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I have a problem with ConversationHandler, that may come from the fact that I haven't understand very well how to use it. I use parent and child ConversationHandlers in PTB like this:

```
...
child_conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
entry_points=[CommandHandler("start_child", start_child_func)],
states={
    CHILD_STATE:  [
        CommandHandler("search", search),
        CommandHandler("add", add),
        CommandHandler("exit", exit),
    ],
},
fallbacks=[MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, fallback_message),],
)


parent_conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
entry_points=[CommandHandler("start_parent", start_parent_func)],
states={
    PARENT_STATE:  [
        CommandHandler("stats", stats),
        child_conv_handler,
    ],
},
fallbacks=[CommandHandler("stop", stop)],
)

application.add_handler(parent_conv_handler)

application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)
```

I make following actions:

1. sent /start_parent to start parent ConversationHandler;
2. start_parent_func callback function returns dialog state PARENT_STATE;
3. sent /start_child to start child ConversationHandler;
4. start_child_func callback function returns dialog state CHILD_STATE;

(attention!)

5. sent /stats command and `CommandHandler("stats", stats)` triggered (stats callback function does its job!).

Its look like all updates firstly checks by handlers from PARENT_STATE. That mean **BOT is in two states simultaneously PARENT_STATE and CHILD_STATE.** For some reason PARENT_STATE has priority. But i need  to CHILD_STATE has priority and checked first.

Yes i can place children_conv_handler in this example first on the list and get result which i want (trigger `MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, fallback_message)`), but what if i need two child_conv_handler1 and child_conv_handler2? In this case i don't know what to do. **How make CHILD_STATE be the main state or how to put parent_conv_handler into some type of "dead end state" while child_conv_handler starts?**

**UPD1:**
Example with two child ConversationHandlers:

```
...

child_conv_handler1 = ConversationHandler(
entry_points=[CommandHandler("start_child1", start_child_func1)],
states={
    CHILD_STATE1:  [
        CommandHandler("stats", child_stats1),
    ],
},
fallbacks=[MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, fallback_message),],
)
     
child_conv_handler2 = ConversationHandler(
entry_points=[CommandHandler("start_child2", start_child_func2)],
states={
    CHILD_STATE2:  [
        CommandHandler("stats", child_stats2),
    ],
},
fallbacks=[MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, fallback_message),],
)


parent_conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
entry_points=[CommandHandler("start_parent", start_parent_func)],
states={
    PARENT_STATE:  [
        CommandHandler("stats", parent_stats),
        child_conv_handler1,
        child_conv_handler2
    ],
},
fallbacks=[CommandHandler("stop", stop)],
)

application.add_handler(parent_conv_handler)

application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing the [docs of `ConversationHandler`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html#telegram.ext.ConversationHandler.params.states):

> The *first* handler whose check_update() method returns True will be used.

Switching the order of the handlers in the `PARENT_STATE` should solve your issue.

**UPD1:** There is no special handling for child conversations in how it is determined which handler will handle an update. So there is currently no built-in way to handle the situation with two child conversations. A workaround could be to put each child conversation in a different parent state or to combine both child conversations into one. I've added this to https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/2770

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Your advice is partially correct. But what i should do with two child_conv_handler1 and child_conv_handler2 (when I don't know the order in which the /stats command is called): look at UPD1 in the question above. 

Is there a way to avoid PARENT_STATE checking and allow only current child_conv_handler checking? Or may be it possible to make priority of PARENT_STATE lower than current CHILD_STATE?